# Set read policy for development blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage-emulator

I would like to know if its possible to set the access policy on my local blob storage. Seems like it defaults to the same settings that you get in the real-world azure storage accounts.

I would like to set read policy to all on a particular blob `bar` to all read. This is possible in Azure but is it possible in the development storage scenario?

`http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/bar/foo.png` 404s when it does exist and can be retrieved via visual studio

Comment: Yes, you can do that. It's the same deal as you would do with Cloud Storage Account: You create a Shared Access Signature with `Read` permission and use the SAS URL to access the blob.

Comment: Thank you your solution pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in powershell. Thanks to Gaurav.

```
>$containerName = 'mycontainer'
>$context = New-AzureStorageContext -ConnectionString 'UseDevelopmentStorage=true;'
>New-AzureStorageContainerSASToken -Name $containerName -Permission rw -Context $context
```

This gives a SAS token for rw permissions that you just append to the end of your request url.